# Questions of complete embedding and dense embedding

Tags: set-theory, forcing

Let $\kappa$ a regular uncountable cardinal and $\mathbb{P}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ poset.

$\mathbb{P}$ has the $\kappa$-Knaster property iff for every $A \subseteq \mathbb{P}$ of size $\kappa$ there is $B \subseteq A$ of size $\kappa$ consisting of pairwise compatible elements.

$\mathbb{P}$ has precaliber $\kappa$ if, given $Q \subseteq \mathbb{P}$ of size, there is a centered $Q^{*} \subseteq Q$ of size $\kappa$.

Questions:

$(i)$ If there is a complete embedding $i:\mathbb{P}\to \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$-Knaster then  $\mathbb{P}$-Knaster.?

$(ii)$ If there is a dense embedding $i:\mathbb{P}\to \mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ has precaliber $\kappa$ then $\mathbb{Q}$ has precaliber.?

Thanks.